# How to use unicode symbols in matplotlib?

Tags: python, unicode, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot

pyplot.figure()
pyplot.xlabel(u"\u2736")
pyplot.show()
```

Here is the simplest code I can create to show my problem. The axis label symbol is meant to be a six-pointed star but it shows as a box. How do I change it so the star is shown? I've tried adding the comment:

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

like previous answers suggested but it didn't work, as well as using `matplotlib.rc` or `matplotlib.rcParams` which also didn't work. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does `\u2736` represent star?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need a font that has the given unicode character, [STIX](http://www.stixfonts.org/install.html) fonts should contain the star symbol.  You'll need to locate or download the STIX fonts, ofcourse any other ttf file with the given symbol should be fine.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pyplot.figure() 
    prop = FontProperties()
    prop.set_file('STIXGeneral.ttf')
    pyplot.xlabel(u"\u2736", fontproperties=prop)
    pyplot.show()
```

Answer (score 5):

To complement @arjenve's answer. To plot a Unicode character, firstly, find which font contains this character, secondly, use that font to plot characters with Matplotlib

## Find a font which contains the character

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43834362/python-unicode-rendering-how-to-know-if-a-unicode-character-is-missing-from-the), we can use [fontTools](https://github.com/fonttools/fonttools) package to find which font contains the character we want to plot.

```
from fontTools.ttLib import TTFont
import matplotlib.font_manager as mfm

def char_in_font(unicode_char, font):
    for cmap in font['cmap'].tables:
        if cmap.isUnicode():
            if ord(unicode_char) in cmap.cmap:
                return True
    return False

uni_char =  u"✹"
# or uni_char = u"\u2739"

font_info = [(f.fname, f.name) for f in mfm.fontManager.ttflist]

for i, font in enumerate(font_info):
    if char_in_font(uni_char, TTFont(font[0])):
        print(font[0], font[1])
```

This script will print a list of font paths and font names (all these fonts support that Unicode Character). Sample output shown below

[image]

Then, we can use the following script to plot this character (see image below)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.font_manager as mfm

font_path = '/usr/share/fonts/gnu-free/FreeSerif.ttf'
prop = mfm.FontProperties(fname=font_path)
plt.text(0.5, 0.5, s=uni_char, fontproperties=prop, fontsize=20)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to implement `@jdhao` code but it was constantly breaking because I also had type 0 fonts in my library.
So here's a tweaked version of his code that does not break with `type 0 fonts` and also enables finding several uni chars at once in the same font by providing the function a `list` of uni chars instead of just 1 uni char.

For more details read the comments throughout the code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from fontTools.ttLib import TTFont
import matplotlib.font_manager as mfm

def print_if_char_in_font(list_unichars, print_true_only=False):

  def char_in_font(unicode_char, font):
    if font.endswith('.ttc'): fontNo = 0 #default is for type -1 so type 0 fonts are going to break the code without this line
    else: fontNo = -1
    font=TTFont(font, fontNumber=fontNo)
    for cmap in font['cmap'].tables: 
      if cmap.isUnicode():
        for i in unicode_char: #tries to match all uni chars with font cmap
          if ord(i) not in cmap.cmap:
            return False
    return True #returns true if all uni chars in given list were found successfully

  font_info = [(f.fname, f.name) for f in mfm.fontManager.ttflist] #list of all font dirs & font names in system

  for i, font in enumerate(font_info):
    try:
      if char_in_font(list_unichars, font[0]) == True: #calls for the defined searching func and checks if True
        print('Yess!! loc:{0}; font name:{1}'.format(font[0], font[1])) #print statement if find is successful
      elif print_true_only==False: print('No :( -- {0}'.format(font[1])) #print statement is find fails
    except:
      print('Error!! Unable to load: {0}, font name: {1}'.format(font[0], font[1])) #if unable to load(type 1 fonts?)
  return

def main(): #this is newbie friendly code, only need to touch 'main' for it to work with your data!
  uni_char = [u'1',u'2', u'*', u"✹"]
  # uni_char = [u"✹"] #or [u"\u2739"] #put inside list even if finding just one char!
  print_if_char_in_font(uni_char, print_true_only=True) #print_true_only is just going to output fonts that satisfy the search

###e.g
# Yess!! loc:C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf\DejaVuSansMono-Bold.ttf; font name:DejaVu Sans Mono
# Yess!! loc:C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf\DejaVuSans.ttf; font name:DejaVu Sans

### print_true_only=False is going to output for all fonts including those which do not satisfy:
# No :( -- Times New Roman
# Yess!! loc:C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf\DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf; font name:DejaVu Sans
# No :( -- Sitka Small

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```