# Showing unicode characters, like করে, in matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I want to plot the text, "কৃষক জমিতে ধান চাষ করে", with matplotlib, what to do...?

I tried the flowing, but it didn't work.

```
s = u"কৃষক জমিতে ধান চাষ করে"
x = 0.2
y = 0.2
matplotlib.pyplot.text(x, y, s)
```

Comment: What version of python are you on?

Comment: I am using Python 3.5.2 @Gx1sptDTDa

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use unicode symbols in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28905938/how-to-use-unicode-symbols-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 6):

## Python3

This should work with a font that contains these unicode characters. I used [kalpurush](https://www.omicronlab.com/bangla-fonts.html) to cover the *Bangla* unicodes. You can pass the font to `matplotlib` like this:

```
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

prop = fm.FontProperties(fname='kalpurush.ttf')
s = u"কৃষক জমিতে ধান চাষ করে"
x = 0.2
y = 0.2
plt.text(x, y, s, fontproperties=prop)
plt.show()
```

[image]

### Bonus: Python2

For python 2 this is super easy. just add this at the top of the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: are you sure that your font covers the unicode characters?

Comment: #!/usr/bin/env python
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

    import matplotlib.font_manager as fm
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    prop = fm.FontProperties(fname='kalpurush.ttf')
    s = u'কৃষক জমিতে ধান চাষ করে'
    x = 0.2
    y = 0.2
    plt.text(x, y, s, fontproperties=prop)
    plt.show()

Comment: the header is only relevant if you use python2. the path to the `ttf` file must be correct. in your case the file has to be where your source code is

Comment: the ttf file is in where my source code is, and I put the header how you wrote.

Comment: I could get the Bengali font as shown in the figure. However, if you notice, the fonts are not in the correct order. "জমিতে"  and "করে" are not plotted correctly. Do you have any suggestions?