# How to decide whether a UTF-8 character is defined in Linux using Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8

I am using Fedora and Python3, and I want to enumerate all the characters by chr, like using the following program.

```
for i in range(0x10ffff + 1) :
    try :
        print(i, chr(i), sep='\t')
    except UnicodeEncodeError :
        print('Error:', i)
```

However, There are many characters which seems to be undefined, and is displayed by a small square with a hex representation inside it (like shown in the picture).

[image]

The question is, how can I use the program decide whether a unicode character is defined (like English letters and Chinese and Japanese characters), or is undefined (like in the picture).

Thanks.

Comment: The meaning of this is that the font you use doesn't have the glyph required to display it, it's not related to Python.

Comment: There's a difference between a character being defined or undefined (and there are also *private use areas* which anyone can define any way they like), and having a font installed that can render that particular glyph.

Comment: So is it possible to determine whether the font file has defined the character with Python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python unicode rendering: how to know if a unicode character is missing from the font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43834362/python-unicode-rendering-how-to-know-if-a-unicode-character-is-missing-from-the)