Add unicode grapheme to matplotlib plot
I'm trying to generate a matplotlib plot that includes emojis.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.font_manager import fontManager

# This is needed to get color emojis to print
matplotlib.use("module://mplcairo.macosx")

# This is the font I'm using, available from Google
fontManager.addfont("/Users/weinberz/Downloads/Noto_Color_Emoji/NotoColorEmoji-Regular.ttf")

plt.figure()
plt.text(0.5, 0.6, "", fontname='Noto Color Emoji')
plt.text(0.5, 0.5, "‍♀️", fontname='Noto Color Emoji')
plt.show()

This results in:

As you can see,  is printed fine. However, ‍♀️, which is a grapheme composed of 4 unicode codepoints ('\U0001F937\U0001F3FB\u200D\u2640\uFE0F'), is printed as each codepoint.
This seems to be a fundamental limitation in matplotlib, which gets each glyph one-at-a-time for drawing. Does anyone know how to pass a grapheme to matplotlib to plot instead of a series of characters?

I'm not going to suggest this as a duplicate since I'm not sure this will definitely lead to the correct answer, but have you seen this SO post? https://stackoverflow.com/q/28905938/12131013

yeah, among others- it’s been a journey haha. as you can see above, i have to use the mplcairo backend to get color emojis, and had to find that Noto font because my system default, Apple Color Emoji, doesn’t work with freetype. I know that Noto contains ‍♀️, it’s just a matter of it being asked to render all four code points simultaneously…

I think the real solution is to tweak TextToPath in matplotlib.backend, but i’m not handy enough for that…

The issue is that most matplotlib backends do not support Opentype rendering of complex grapheme clisters. You need to use mplcairo as your back end. If you are already using the raqm backend for pillow this will be straightforward. Otherwise you need to install libraqm and all it's dependencies.
